# How to change color of options in Wireshark in Kali linux?

Tags: linux, wireshark, kali-linux

I am using wireshark in kali linux and all the options are coming out in white. I am not able to read a single thing,
[image]

Is there any way to change this? I have tried and search the internet for past one hour before posting, but got no help. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kali Linux, you can change the look, try changing the style to Kali-Dark.
And then there are Qt5 Settings, and there you can customize the display of windows and the application header as you like.
in the terminal type `qt5ct` and you need to change the `Color Scheme`

Comment: Thanks it helped :)